# can I use decorators on object properties?

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator

Normally I apply the decorator like this:

```
class SpecialMethods {
    @Deco
    static someMethod() {
    }
}
```

Is there also some way to use it with a plain object rather than a class:

```
const SpecialMethods = {
    @Deco
    someMethod: () => {}
}
```

Comment: Which decorators are you refering to? The proposal ones?

Comment: What's a `abstract class`? This doesn't look like JavaScript.

Comment: @Bergi Sorry, I am currently working a lot with typescript. I have removed abstract

Answer (score 6):

Yes, but its not very practical. You can invoke the decorator for the properties of an object, but not in the same way as you would decorate a class and its content.

Given the following decorator:

```
const TestDecorator = (at: string) => {
    return function (target: any, prop: string, descriptor?: PropertyDescriptor) {
        console.log(`decorated at ${at}}`);
    }
}
```

Would be used as followed in a class:

```
class TestClass {
    @TestDecorator('class method')
    public testMethod() { }
}
```

However, it can't be applied the same way as above for a property:

```
const testObj = {
    @TestDecorator('property method')
    testMethod: () => { }
};
```

To work around this, you can invoke the decorator at the property.

At first you have to declare your object with all its properties:

```
const testObj = {
    testMethod: () => { }
};
```

My decorator expects a curried value:

```
const deco = TestDecorator('property method');
```

Now you have to manually invoke the `deco` decorator for the property in `testObj`:

```
deco(testObj, 'testMethod');
```

If you need the `propertyDescriptor` in your decorator (it is not in the OP), you'll have to manually provide it as well:

```
deco(testObj, 'testMethod', Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(testObj, 'testMethod'));
```

Here is a [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20TestDecorator%20%3D%20(at%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20function%20(target%3A%20any%2C%20prop%3A%20string%2C%20descriptor%3F%3A%20PropertyDescriptor)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20descriptor%20%3D%20descriptor%20%7C%7C%20Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target%2C%20prop)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%60decorated%20at%20%24%7Bat%7D%60)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20TestClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%40TestDecorator('class%20method')%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20testMethod()%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20test%20%3D%20new%20TestClass()%3B%0D%0Atest.testMethod()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20won't%20compile%3A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20const%20testObj%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20%40TestDecorator('property%20method')%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20testMethod%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20testObj%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20testMethod%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20deco%20%3D%20TestDecorator('property%20method')%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adeco(testObj%2C%20'testMethod')%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20deco(testObj%2C%20'testMethod'%2C%20Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(testObj%2C%20'testMethod'))%0D%0A%0D%0AtestObj.testMethod()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A). Check the output in the console.

Comment: Why are you not passing a property descriptor?

Comment: @Bergi There is no need for that in this example. This only shows how to invoke a decorator for an `object`, I am not manipulating anything from within the decorator.

Comment: Well yeah but it depends a lot on what the OPs actual decorator does, so it would be good to give a general solution or at least state that it's only a reduced example.